# Server management IPMI

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool

I have a couple of server I would like to manage, and I will be using IPMI.
My question is, what tool should I use? I know about IPMITool and such. But there are also some tools delivered with the Server. Like the DRAC with Dell. Is it better for me to use something like IPMITool? or would I have more options when using the standard tool delivered with the server? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've only got a couple of servers you can use the web management interface provided by the server BMC.  As far as I'm aware, they all provide that.

When the server boots up you should see what IP address the BMC shows up as.  Connect to that with your web browser.  If not, go into the BIOS and find out whether the BMC is using a dedicated port, or a shared port and see if it's set to DHCP.

If you still can't get it working, consult the manual that came with the server.

This interface will allow you to do things like, power off & on the server, use the remote console, view the motherboard temps & stats etc.  And of course, change the parameters of the IPMI including changing the default password.  I always recommend setting the LAN to dedicated mode than shared as then you know which port it will appear on as it doesn't appear on all ports.

Comment: Well, it's about 30 servers. But I am unsure whether the IPMITool has the same functionalities.

Comment: ipmitool can be used to do pretty much what the web interface can do.  It takes a bit more learning but it's not hard and you could create some scripts so simplify it's usage.